# Alembic migration shows error in mssql in windows server. How do i solve this?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, flask, migration, alembic

I tried to extract json object from a column in migration. I get this error

```
__main__ ERROR (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '>'
```

Here is my code. how do i solve this?

```
def upgrade():
    op.execute("CREATE VIEW MESSAGE_VIEW AS SELECT "
               "event_messages.message_id,"
               "event_messages.event_id,"
               "event_messages.message,"
               "event_messages.message::json->'message' AS message_input "
               "FROM event_messages "
               "LEFT JOIN chatbot_events ON event_messages.event_id = chatbot_events.event_id;")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect.

you cannot run this command in MSSQL. becuase your command is specific to PostgreSQL.

**event_messages.message::json->'message' AS message_input**  is a JSON Datatype In PostgreSQL that is not supported in MSSQL.

The correct statement for MSSQL is:

```
def upgrade():
    op.execute("CREATE VIEW MESSAGE_VIEW AS SELECT "
               "event_messages.message_id,"
               "event_messages.event_id,"
               "event_messages.message,"
               "event_messages.message AS message_input "
               "FROM event_messages "
               "LEFT JOIN chatbot_events ON event_messages.event_id = chatbot_events.event_id;")
```

for more information read [this](https://datavirtuality.com/blog-json-in-postgresql/)

Comment: That works on Postgresql. I am actually extracting an object "message" from json data here.

Comment: I Edited my answer base on your comment. please re-read it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i want to extract specific object (For example, "incoming_message") form that json data, how do i do that?